# Classifying 'undefined' types

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to classify `undefined` in these cases?

```
var arr = [];
var a = arr[0];

console.log(arr.length); // 0
console.log(a === undefined); // true
console.log(typeof a === 'undefined'); // true
```

and

```
var arr = [undefined];
var a = arr[0];

console.log(arr.length); // 1
console.log(a === undefined); // true
console.log(typeof a === 'undefined'); // true
```

I want to know a specific index in the `arr` array contains an element or not.

In the first case: `arr[0]` doesn't contain any element (NOT an element with `undefined` value).

In this second case: `arr[0]` contains 1 element (with `undefined` value).

Not using `length` property, is there a way to classify them? Because some case I don't know exactly the `length`.

**UPDATE:**

I want to talk about `undefined` because sometimes `arr` may contain an element like this:

```
var e = [].find(x => x === 0); // undefined
arr.push(e); // arr contains 1 element now
```

Comment: tip: don't use undefined as a value for a variable, unless you actually want it to be considered as not existing. For your case, the difference is more than length: in second case you can loop on the array pretty well, and even get the numeric index of your array element

Comment: why don't you use null's instead of undefined?

Comment: You can use length to differentiate. At the same time you can use `Array.indexOf` Method to check if it is actually present or not

Comment: @Kaddath I cannot avoid at all.

Comment: Try `index in arr`.

Comment: if you use `findIndex()`, you will always be able to test existence of elements even if the value is undefined: `e = [].findIndex(x => x === 0); if(e > -1){ /* do something */ }` (beware that not found is -1 here, not undefined)

Comment: Checking index of `undefined` in the array? Good idea. I will try.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot differentiate between the values themselves. Basically you want to see if an object / array has a key, regardless of the value. To do this you can use `hasOwnProperty`:

```
[].hasOwnProperty(0) --> false
[undefined].hasOwnProperty(0) --> true
```